# Flask configuration Error

Tags: python, flask

I'm having issues making flask work. I'm a noob and still learning about Linux. I'm getting this (very intimidating looking)error after running:

`flask run`

```
root@DESKTOP-TV7O885:/mnt/c/Projects/app_1# flask run
 * Serving Flask app "application"
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2018-03-12 14:10:00,550] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/mnt/c/Projects/app_1/application.py", line 7, in index
    return render_template("index.html")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 133, in render_template
    return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 57, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 85, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
TemplateNotFound: index.html
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Mar/2018 14:10:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

and the page then drops

```
 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

I'm also getting a pylint error on VSCODE:

```
 E0401:Unable to import 'flask'
```

I understand its probably a relatively simple error because of a bad configuration or installing something wrong. I've been trying to figure this out myself but I have a lot of gaps in my knowledge.

I'm using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows and I think that's why i'm having issues. if anyone could help me or atleast point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

On the call stack in the exception, you must go from bottom to top, until you find a file in your project. This is the starting point. In your case, it is:

```
File "/mnt/c/Projects/app_1/application.py", line 7, in index
  return render_template("index.html")
```

You say you have a template named `index.html`, but (as the exception error), Flask cannot find it.  Check that you have such template in the correct place, and you define correctly (when you call `Flask` constructor) the location of template directory.